# trying to retrieve meta data, but getting C:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command, when referencing a package with spaces

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./mdapipkg -u myemail@email.com -p 'My Package'
```

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

however

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./mdapipkg -u myemail@email.com -p 'MyPackage'
```

doesn't give this error, it just says:

> The metadata retrieve operation failed: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: No package named 'MyPackage' found.

Comment: Don't have a windows computer to test it on, but try [the `^` symbol](https://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks). Supposedly it escapes the spaces, not sure if it'll work through a command.

Comment: no such luck, it just weird.

Comment: According to any documentation I can find, enclosing the string with `''` should work, ie: `$ sfdx force:package2:create -n PackageName -d 'My New Package' -o Unlocked`. Might be worth going to the sfdx community & reporting this as a bug.

Comment: Have you tried with a package that actually doesn't contain a space, just to test? Also, using CMD or PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the reason it wasn't working was due to the production site not being a development hub anymore. Higher ups made changes.